# Python character name

Tags: python

First I assigned a variable

```
character_name = "Patrice"
```

On the print function, I wrote

```
print( " Patrice does a wonderful job at his workplace ")
```

Instead of writing Patrice on the `print` function, I wanted to declare the variable that would print Patrice, How would I do it?

Comment: Why not `print(f"{character_name} does a wonderful job at his workplace")`?

Comment: `print(f"{character_name} does a wonderful job at his workplace")`

Answer (score 1):

There's various ways to achive this, you might want to look at Pythons [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/):

```py
print(f'{character_name} does a wonderful job at his workplace')
```